# Narrative tenses

Tags: past-tense

> Gary was fed up. He <sup>1</sup> ______ (wait) for his girlfriend for over an hour and she still <sup>2</sup> ______ (not turn up). Just as he <sup>3</sup> ______ (contemplate) going home, she walked round the corner looking please with herself. Her smile <sup>4</sup> ______ (vanish), however, when she saw the expression on Gary's face.
>   — What's wrong? she asked.
>   — You're late again, he said.
>   — No, I'm not, she replied, The clocks <sup>5</sup> ______ (go back) last night. You <sup>6</sup> ______ (be) early!

These are my choices for the narrative tenses:

> Gary was fed up. He ***had been waiting*** for his girlfriend for over an hour and she still ***didn't turn up***. Just as he ***had contemplated*** going home, she walked round the corner looking pleased with herself. Her smile ***was vanishing***, however, when she saw the expression on Gary's face.
>   — What's wrong? she asked.
>   — You're late again, he said.
>   — No, I'm not, she replied, The clocks ***went back*** last night. You ***had been*** early!

Are my choices good? Are there better options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your choices are pretty good, but can be improved:

> Gary was fed up. He ***had been waiting*** for his girlfriend for over an hour

Good. This one I like.

> and she still ***didn't turn up***.

This one I don't like quite as much. The first sentence is in the past tense ("Gary was fed up."), so this shouldn't be in the present for sure. A better option would be "***and she still hadn't turned up.***"

> Just as he ***had contemplated*** going home,

"Had contemplated" doesn't work here. Her action is interrupting what he was doing, so the preterite is better - "Just as he ***contemplated*** going home,".>

> she walked round the corner looking pleased with herself. Her smile ***was vanishing***, however, when she saw the expression on Gary's face.

While vanishing is technically a process, it isn't supposed to be one in this case. It is something that happens instantly here. You would typically say, "Her smile ***vanished***, however."

> — What's wrong? she asked.
>   — You're late again, he said.
>   — No, I'm not, she replied, The clocks ***went back*** last night.

Good here.

> You ***had been*** early!

I'm actually not completely sure here. You have two options. Technically, "You **were** early" is correct, but I think "You **are** early" could be used as well, because it is a response to "You're late," and I like the parallelism that that creates. The official answer is likely "You **were** early," so you should probably stick with that.

Comment: Yes, about the last one, I thought the same, but it was meant to be with a past tense, so I sticked with **were**.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take your story change-by-change with some possible fill-ins:

> Gary was fed up. He **had been waiting** for his girlfriend for over an hour and she still **hadn't turned** up. Just as he **contemplated** going home, she walked round the corner looking pleased with herself. Her smile **vanished**, however, when she saw the expression on Gary's face.
>   — What's wrong? she asked.
>   — You're late again, he said.
>   — No, I'm not, she replied, The clocks **moved back** last night. You **were** early!

The scenario of the story begins the the **past perfect** and proceeds to the **simple past**.

> ...**had not turned up**... fits better with ...**had been waiting**...

> Just as he **contemplated**

moves the time frame to forward to the **simple past** from when Gary was **originally waiting**, and fits well with

> she walked.

> Her smile **was vanishing**... when

sounds awkward since it leaves the reader hanging, *things* **vanish from** *somewhere*, plausible choices might be

> Her smile **was vanishing** from view... when
>   Her smile **was vanishing** from her face... when

However, the **simple past**

> Her smile **vanished**

is more succinct and has more dramatic effect.

During time changes i.e. **standard time**, **daylight savings time**, **leap second**, it is normal to say that the clocks **moved forward** or the clocks **moved back**, the hour change is implied:

> The clocks **moved back** last night.

By this point in the story, the action has moved to the present, Gary was off by an hour, so the **simple past** simply states this:

> You **were** early.

Answer (score 0):

Past perfect is a complicated tense for even the most experienced writers.

1. **Had been waiting** is fine.
2. **Had not arrived** is a better solution, but yours is ok.
3. **Contemplated**, you are back into "standard" narrative.

"around" the corner

4. **Vanished** (simple past) is a better solution than continuous past.
5. **Turned back** last night is a better solution. Correct tense but this is an English idiom. Yours would be understood.
6. **Are**. Dialogue occurs in present tense unless the character is speaking of the past or future.